# log4net log messages only to a few appenders

Tags: c#, log4net, log4net-configuration

I am using log4net api for logging in my WinForms application. I have multiple appenders: RollingFileAppender and TextBoxAppender (custom appender).

I want to log some Error messages only in the log file (RollingFileAppender) and not to the text box (TextBoxAppender), and some other messages to both. How can I achieve it? Note that the messages are of same level i.e. all ERROR messages.

Thanks.

EDIT 1:

Specifically, I want to display simple one line ERROR messages in the UI as well as log file, but StackTraces only in the log file.

Comment: Although you *can* do this with just one logger (through suitable application of filters) this goes against the grain of log4net. What you typically want to do is use separate loggers for each configuration and add appenders to those loggers as appropriate (`FileLogger`, `UILogger`, `UniversalLogger`, something like that). Note that loggers can share appenders.

Comment: Even if I were to use separate loggers, how can I filter the messages of the same level, example some messages of log level ERROR to be shown in the UILogger, and some messages of same log level ERROR, NOT to be shown. Basically, then what you are suggesting is that every place I may need to call both the loggers as required, like logger1.Error(), and logger2.Error()

Comment: The use of multiple logger instances may be fine where I want to send the log message only to 1 destination, but majority of the cases require messages to be sent to BOTH the loggers

Comment: If you need both you'd use `UniversalLogger`, which you would set up to have both appenders. But yes, this approach requires that for every message you know which appender(s) you want to have, and use the appropriate logger. A message only ever has to be sent to one *logger*, a logger can have as many appenders as you like. If you cannot pick the logger in advance, you have to use filters, but that's more complicated.

Comment: Ok. Yes understood. This may be fine if I dont get any other solution. But is there a way to achieve this with a SINGLE logger?

Comment: You said it can be done with just one logger through suitable application of filters, but how do I filter when the messages are of same level. Specifically, I want to display simple ERROR messages in the UI as well as   log file, but StackTraces only in the log file.

Comment: If you want messages to go to both appenders, but have only the file appender log stack traces of exceptions, that's far simpler, because you can configure the appender with an appropriate `PatternLayout`. The trick is that you have to use the overloads of the methods that take an `Exception` as an argument and not just pass `Exception.ToString()` to the logger. If you insist on logging it as a string, you could still filter (with a `StringMatchFilter`, for example) but that gets hacky.

Comment: Currently, I am logging Stack Traces using logger.Error("Stack Trace: " + ex.StackTrace);. The 2nd overload of the Error method takes (object message, Exception exception). If I use the 2nd overload, what do I pass in the 1st parameter, and how do I configure the PatternLayout. This might solve my requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it, you actually want messages to go to both appenders, but have only one of them log stack traces. First, log messages including the exception as an exception, don't use `Exception.ToString()`:

```
logger.Error($"Something went wrong frobbing the widget: {ex.Message}", ex);
```

Then your logger can use multiple appenders, some of which omit the stack trace by telling log4net we'll be taking care of exceptions (by actually doing nothing with them):

```xml
<appender name="TextBoxAppender" type="MyAppenders.TextBoxAppender">
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <ignoresException value="false" />
        <conversionPattern value="%m%n" /> 
    </layout>
</appender>
```

And others with full details:

```xml
<appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    ...
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%d{ISO8601} [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>
```

Comment: For the TextBoxAppender, I set ignoresException to true, and I changed the code to: logger.Error("Stack Trace: ", ex);. Still the Text Box displays the Stack Trace. What did I miss? My conversion pattern is: <conversionPattern value="[LOG] %date{yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt}: [%-5level] %message%newline" />

Comment: Whoops, I'm confused. `ignoresException` should be `false`, to indicate the layout *is* handling the exception -- by not printing it.

Comment: Ok Yes :) By setting it to false, I am able to suppress the Stack Trace in the UI. But since my code is: logger.Error("Stack Trace: ", ex); the UI displays the words "Stack Trace". What should I pass in the 1st parameter, if I dont want the UI to display anything?

Comment: If I pass an empty string, the UI displays a blank line.

Comment: And if I call the 1st overloaded method like: logger.Error(ex); (passing the Exception object rather than the string), then the UI displays the Stack Trace!

Comment: What *do* you want the UI to display on an error, then? Customarily something along the lines of "an error happened". Don't log the exception *separately* from the error message, but as one event, and you won't have this problem. The idea is that both logs show the *message* you're passing in, but only one also shows the exception. If you want to set things up so that all events with exceptions log *nothing* in the UI, you can do that with a custom `Filter` that overrides `Decide` to return `Deny` when the `LoggingEvent` has a non-`null` `ExceptionObject`. This isn't "natural", though.

Comment: ah, I have 3 log destinations actually. One is the log file which should have all the messages. Then on screen, I have 2 text boxes: the 1st displays a running log of what the program is doing; the 2nd displays only those messages which are meant for the user to review and take necessary actions if any. For errors which are due to wrong data in an Excel file, I display the message in both the text boxes, for which I have written a helper SendMessage() method.

Comment: So there are scenarios where I call the SendMessage method to log the message to all 3 destinations, followed by the call to log just the Stack Trace to the log file

Comment: The SendMessage calls the logger to log the message to the 1st textbox and the log file, and then raises an event, so that other UI objects can update them as necessary. I catch that event in my Form and display the message in the 2nd text box. These errors are logged from the business class, which does not have direct access to the Form's textboxes.

Comment: So effectively, the SendMessage ends up logging the message to all 3 destinations. Hence I have no more "message" to log when I want to log the Stack Trace. If there is no other solution, I need to overload the SendMessage to take an Exception object as well, which will pass the Exception to logger.

Comment: You may be overcomplicating things by insisting everything goes to log4net first and then has to be filtered and redirected by log4net somehow. Specifically, it sounds like the decision which logger(s) to use could be made by your own code based on flags/properties of the event in question. You *can* filter in log4net based on the message text (`StringMatchFilter`), but maintaining the filters would be a pain. Consider using something richer than a plain `string`, and also consider not using log4net at all for the UI feedback. Flexibility is great, but there's a cost.

Comment: Hmm, if I have to consider not using log4net at all for the UI feedback, do I send all log messages from the business class to the UI using events? Are you suggesting this?

Comment: You can go two ways with that: expose events from the business class (optional for consumers) or write something that's much like `ILog` but with more semantics (mandatory). Either way, the idea is to have your own code there to do UI updates rather than getting to fit the square log4net peg into the round UI hole.

Comment: Ok. Was rethinking on log4net; observed that the parameter to the method logger.Error is an object; can't I set up the filter to ignore messages based on the type of the object? And if possible without writing a custom appender or a custom filter?

Comment: You could, but not without a custom filter that works with the `LoggingEvent.MessageObject` property. There's no built-in filter for it.

Comment: I realized that TextBoxAppender is any way a custom appender, for which I have having the source in my project. And TextBoxAppender is the one where I need to suppress Exception object logging, so all it required was 2 lines of code: if (loggingEvent.MessageObject is Exception) { //do nothing }

Comment: If required, I can make the TextBoxAppender configurable by having a property to log or not log exception messages. I am yet to figure that out.

Comment: Ok. I am able to make it configurable by adding a property in the TextBoxAppender

Comment: Is there a quick way to support this property across all the appenders, including the inbuilt appenders, without overriding each and every appender? May be a code in one of the base classes?

Comment: Accepting your answer as you gave me lots of insights.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to output different messages to different appenders should be the `ForwardingAppender` (the documentation on logging.apache seems to be down at the present, but anyway here is the link: https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.ForwardingAppender.html)

Here you can filter based on loglevel (most examples) but also based on log messages (have a look here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140911/log-net-Tutorial, Paragraph "StringMatchFilter")

At least, this helps you to bring just this one message to one specific Appender.
To make sure how to omit the stacktrace see Jeroen Mosterts answer